# issues Regarding The DataGrid Control in Silverlight sdk and Child inputs, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I'm writing a Silverlight 5 web application using the DataGrid control. I have an interesting issue indeed.

I'm using templated columns for each row. Each row represents one data item in an observable collection.

Each row holds one check box, one text block, and one text box.

The environment that my error occurs in is one where there are more rows than silverlight can draw on screen thus enables the vertical scollbar.

when a user inputs information into more than one text box and/or more than one checkbox then scrolls down random boxes are checked and random text boxes are populated with similar/partial input from previously populated text boxes.

when a user scrolls up and then back down different rows are populated at random. I've tried this with bound and unbound inputs and the result is the same.

I've mocked up an example that shows this issue

here is the xaml for the MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataGrid_bug_repro.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Margin="60 0 0 0">Bound to Data Items</TextBlock>
    <sdk:DataGrid Name="dgBound" Height="280" Width="680" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="12" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox Width="40" Tag="{Binding ID}"  IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="name" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="txt" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding txt}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
        <TextBlock Margin="60 0 0 0">Not Bound to Data Items</TextBlock>
    <sdk:DataGrid Name="dgNotBound" Height="280" Width="680" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="12" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox Width="40" Tag="{Binding ID}"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="name" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="txt" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox Text="" />
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the C# code for the MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace DataGrid_bug_repro
{
public class ITEM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ID = string.Empty;
    private bool _Selected = false;
    private string _Name = string.Empty;
    private string _txt = string.Empty;

    public string ID
    {
        get{return _ID;}
        set { _ID = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "ID"); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "Name"); }
    }

    public string txt
    {
        get { return _txt; }
        set { _txt = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "txt"); }
    }

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _Selected; }
        set { _Selected = value; onPropertyChanged(this, "Selected"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void onPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
  }
  public partial class MainPage : UserControl
  {
    public MainPage()
    {
        ObservableCollection<ITEM> Items = new ObservableCollection<ITEM> { 
                                new ITEM { ID="1", Name="Gomez" },
                                new ITEM { ID="2", Name="Morticia" },
                                new ITEM { ID="3", Name="Pugsly" },
                                new ITEM { ID="4", Name="Wednesday" },
                                new ITEM { ID="5", Name="Pubert" },
                                new ITEM { ID="6", Name="Uncle Fester" },
                                new ITEM { ID="7", Name="Grandmama" },
                                new ITEM { ID="8", Name="Thing" },
                                new ITEM { ID="9", Name="Lurch" },
                                new ITEM { ID="10", Name="Cousin Itt" },
                                new ITEM { ID="11", Name="Cousin Cackle" },
                                new ITEM { ID="12", Name="Kitty Cat" },
                                new ITEM { ID="13", Name="Aristotle" },
                                new ITEM { ID="14", Name="Homer" },
                                new ITEM { ID="15", Name="Tristan" },
                                new ITEM { ID="16", Name="Isolde" },
                                new ITEM { ID="17", Name="Zelda" },
                                new ITEM { ID="18", Name="Cleopatra" },
                                new ITEM { ID="19", Name="Bernice" },
                                new ITEM { ID="20", Name="Ophelia" },
                                new ITEM { ID="21", Name="Melancholia" },
                                new ITEM { ID="22", Name="Hester" },
                                new ITEM { ID="23", Name="Norman Normanmeyers" },
                                new ITEM { ID="24", Name="Normina Normanmeyers" },
                                new ITEM { ID="25", Name="N.J. Normanmeyers" }      };
        InitializeComponent();

        dgBound.ItemsSource = Items;
        dgNotBound.ItemsSource = Items;
    }
}
}
```

Has anyone seen this before? and is there a work around? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too in the past, and I don't remember exactly how to fix it. But, looking at the code this might be it:

Try adding an event handler in your code behind for IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged like so,

```
private void DataGrid_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(object sender,     System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
        (sender as DataGrid).CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
}
```

If this doesn't work, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that event is not available to me. It looks like that event isn't readily available to inheritors of the Control type.  I did try something similar, attaching a text change listener and a got focus listener utilizing a flag setting scenario. This did not work because the text changed event never fired on the rows that were not touched by the user,yet populated all the same. It was a good Idea though. Definitely something that I did not think of.

Comment: @AndrewTM Yeah, mine was a WPF solution. You have to realize this problem is likely caused by row virtualization (reusing the controls). But, you'd think that it should work by default... Do you have the ability in Silverlight to disable row virtualization? EnableRowVirtualization="False"? I'd at least give that a try to see if it affected the problem

Comment: I did not have the option to actually turn it off. It was there but it was read only.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Utilizing TwoWay binding mode actually nullifies this issue. I'm not sure why but it probably has something to do with row visualization. I just thought I'd let you all know the work around.